# Android screenshot capture for rooting device

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I tried screenshot capture application for layout only take screenshot its working fine.I want to ask for ovelay button every page display after button click current screen how to take capture screenshot.please help me.

Comment: so you want take screenshot of current screen

Comment: yes,i want to take screenshot of current screen

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
                   View vieww=findViewById(R.id.main);
                    //View v1 = view.getRootView();
                    //v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    //Bitmap b = v.getDrawingCache();
                    //imgcapmain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    View v1 = vieww.getRootView();
                    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
                    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                    imgcapmain.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Get root view from current activity

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

Comment: findViewById(R.id.main) this is layout xml are content view screen

Comment: it is a main xml file rootview

Comment: i tried second one root view code is working.but saved in sdcard its fine after screenshot open i got this error in  "Couldnot open this image".how to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Initialize variables

```
Bitmap bmScreen;
ImageView bmImage;
View screen;
```

and in OnClickListener

```
   screen.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   bmScreen = screen.getDrawingCache();
```